# Check database if checkbox value exists then display its value in a div, if it doesnt hide div

Tags: php

I have a post.php file which asks a stack of questions, among st them is a checkbox that has different values. On submit data is passed to db.

I have this hook that with which I can display the value of that checkbox where I want it. However, there are certain instances where that question (checkbox) is disable and therefore does not have a value.

I would like to know how to check if there is a value in db and then display it in a div, and if there isnt a value hide that div.

this is my div with that hook:

```
<div class="pull-left col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
   <h4 class="stanje"><?php echo item_condition(); ?></h4>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me, I am new to PHP.

Comment: `item_condition()` returns false if the checkbox doesn't have a value?

Comment: There is a label "Condition:" before the value, so it just returns a blank label. I would like to completely hide that div if there is no value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could nest an `if` statement around your `<h4>`

```
<div class="pull-left col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
<!-- change your condition if as needed, to check if there is a value -->
   <?php if(strlen(item_condition()) > 11) { ?> 
       <h4 class="stanje"><?php echo item_condition(); ?></h4>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but that will still display a label "Condition:" and nothing else. I would like to completely hide that <h4> tag, show nothing if the item_condition has no value.

Comment: @AlexRns change the if statement to only enter if the return from `item_condition()` is differente from "Condition:". Check edited answer. But make sure there isn't a space after `:` from the returning string

Comment: I think I maybe didnt properly explain everything: 
the checkbox on the form page has 3 different values, it is a required input so it cannot have blank value. However, depending on other questions that checkbox may disappear (be disabled) and therefore no value is required.
echo item_condition() returns a value if there is one, if there isnt it returns blank, however, there is a label somewhere in the code  of that hook that is placed before the value thats says "Condition:". When there is no value in db echo item_condition() returns this line "Condition: ". I would like to hide that line.

Comment: @AlexRns I'm sorry if I didn't understand correctly your question, I thought your `item_condition()` returned a string like `"Condition:<value>"`.

Comment: yes it does return that line ("Condition:<value>") if there is  a value, if there isnt a value than it returns "Condition: " and that looks ugly so I would like not to show it when there isnt a value.

Comment: Then I think my solution works, you just need to check the condition inside the `if` statement. Or you could get the length of the string when there is no value, and make sure the `if` will only be true if the returned string is longer (edited my answer with this condition).

Comment: @AlexRns I'm considering that when you get an empty value, your returning string will have length 11 (`"Condition: "`)